Does a fully faithful and essentially surjective exact functor between triangulated categories have a quasi-inverse the 2-cat of triangulated cats?
$\def\D{\mathcal{D}}
\def\I{\mathcal{I}}
\def\A{\mathcal{A}}$Triangulated categories are the objects of a 2-category $\mathsf{Triang}$: the 1-morphisms are the exact functors $(F,\xi)$ of triangulated categories. The 2-morphisms are the natural transformations between triangulated functors where shifts are compatible with the isos $\xi$ (see commutative square after Definition 014V in Section 05QK). Suppose $(F,\xi):\D\to\D'$ is a fully faithful and essentially surjective exact functor between triangulated categories. Denote as $T:\D\to\D$ and $T':\D'\to\D'$ the translation functors (also called shift functors).

Can we always find a quasi-inverse of $(F,\xi)$ in $\mathsf{Triang}$? That is, an exact functor $(G,\xi'):\D'\to\D$ such that in $\mathsf{Triang}$ there are 2-isomorphisms $\eta:(1_\D,1_T)\cong (G,\xi')(F,\xi)$ and $\varepsilon:(F,\xi)(G,\xi')\cong (1_{\D'},1_{T'})$. Explicitly, this means $\eta:1_\D\cong GF$, $\varepsilon:FG\cong 1_{\D'}$ and
\begin{gather}
\tag{1}\label{comp}
T\eta_X=\xi'_{FX}\circ G\xi_X\circ\eta_{TX}\\
\varepsilon_{T'Y}=T'\varepsilon_Y\circ\xi_{GY}\circ F\xi'_Y
\end{gather}

Here are my thoughs so far: For simplicity, let's assume the translation functor $T$ and $T'$ are automorphisms. Let $G$ be a quasi-inverse of $F$ in the standard 2-category of categories (we are using some version of choice). We may suppose that $F$ and $G$ give an adjoint equivalence, i.e., there are isomorphisms $\eta:1_\D\cong GF$, $\varepsilon:FG\cong 1_{\D'}$ satisfying the triangle identities. Then $G$ is exact, 0A8D. By looking at the proof of 0A8D, one can compute explicitly the isomorphism $\xi'_Y:GT'Y\to T'GY$ to be
$$
\xi_Y'=T[GT^{-1}(\varepsilon_{TY}\circ \xi_{T^{-1}GTY}^{-1})\circ\eta_{T^{-1}GTY}].
$$
But now will relations \eqref{comp} really hold?

Motivation: I started thinking about this after reading the proof in Section 013U that the composite $K^+(\I)\hookrightarrow K^+(\A)\to D^+(\A)$ is an equivalence in $\mathsf{Triang}$ whenever $\A$ is an abelian category with enough injectives (where $K^+(\I)\subset K^+(\A)$ is the full triangulated subcategory whose objects are the complexes whose terms are all injective objects in $\mathcal{A}$). The functor $K^+(\I)\to D^+(\A)$ is exact for it is the composite of exact functors. On the other hand, it is not difficult to show that $K^+(\I)\to D^+(\A)$ is fully faithful and essentially surjective [013V]. If for each $K^\bullet\in K^+(\mathcal{A})$, one assumes an injective resolution $K^\bullet\to j(K^\bullet)$ as given, then one can construct the quasi-inverse $D^+(\A)\to K^+(\I)$ in $\mathsf{Triang}$ (I provide the missing details in the last paragraph of this comment). I was wondering if we could avoid giving the resolution $K^\bullet\to j(K^\bullet)$ to obtain the quasi-inverse in $\mathsf{Triang}$ (admitting some version of choice to construct it, sure).

$\def\D{\mathcal{D}}$The answer is yes. So far, we have:

An exact functor $(F,\xi):(\mathcal{D},T)\to(\mathcal{D}',T')$ (which is f.f. and essentially surjective).

A quasi-inverse $G:\mathcal{D}'\to\mathcal{D}$ of $F$ in the 2-cat of 1-cats.

Natural isomorphisms $\eta:1_\D\cong GF$, $\varepsilon:FG\cong 1_{\D'}$. Since any equivalence in a 2-cat can be promoted to an adjoint equivalence (changing possibly the quasi-inverse), we may assume $\eta$ and $\varepsilon$ satisfy the triangle identities.


From the data 1+2+3, we want to define $\xi':GT'\Rightarrow TG$ satisfying \eqref{comp}. In particular, the following should hold:
\begin{align*}
F\xi_Y'
&=\xi^{-1}_{GY}\circ T'\varepsilon_Y^{-1}\circ\varepsilon_{T'Y}\\
\xi_Y'
&=\eta_{TGY}^{-1}\circ GF\xi_Y'\circ\eta_{GT'Y}
\end{align*}
Plugging the former into the latter relation, we can define
\begin{align*}
\xi_Y'
&:=\eta_{TGY}^{-1}
\circ G(\xi^{-1}_{GY}\circ T'\varepsilon_Y^{-1}\circ\varepsilon_{T'Y})
\circ\eta_{GT'Y}\\
&=\eta_{TGY}^{-1}
\circ G(\xi^{-1}_{GY}\circ T'\varepsilon_Y^{-1}),
\end{align*}
where we have used a triangle equality. We now verify relations \eqref{comp}. On the one hand,
\begin{align*}
\xi'_{FX}\circ G\xi_X\circ\eta_{TX}
&=\eta_{TGFX}^{-1}
\circ G(\xi^{-1}_{GFX}\circ T'\varepsilon_{FX}^{-1})
\circ G\xi_X\circ\eta_{TX}\\
&=\eta_{TGFX}^{-1}
\circ G(\xi^{-1}_{GFX}\circ T'F\eta_X
\circ \xi_X)\circ\eta_{TX}
&\text{by a triangle equality}\\
&=\eta_{TGFX}^{-1}
\circ GFT\eta_X\circ\eta_{TX}
&\text{by naturality of }\xi\\
&=T\eta_X
&\text{by naturality of }\eta.
\end{align*}
On the other hand,
\begin{align*}
T'\varepsilon_Y\circ\xi_{GY}\circ F\xi'_Y
&=T'\varepsilon_Y\circ\xi_{GY}
\circ F\eta_{TGY}^{-1}
\circ FG\xi^{-1}_{GY}\circ FGT'\varepsilon_Y^{-1}\\
&=T'\varepsilon_Y\circ\xi_{GY}
\circ \varepsilon_{FTGY}
\circ FG\xi^{-1}_{GY}\circ FGT'\varepsilon_Y^{-1}
&\text{by a triangle equality}\\
&=T'\varepsilon_Y
\circ\varepsilon_{T'FGY}\circ FGT'\varepsilon_Y^{-1}
&\text{by naturality of }\varepsilon\\
&=\varepsilon_{T'Y}
&\text{by naturality of }\varepsilon.
\end{align*}
It is left to verify that $(G,\xi'):\D'\to\D$ is exact. Suppose $\Delta=(X\to Y\to Z\xrightarrow{f}T'X)$ is a distinguished triangle in $\D'$. We want to show that $G\Delta=(GX\to GY\to GZ\xrightarrow{\xi_X'\circ Gf}TGX)$ is a d.t. in $\D$. Since $F$ is a f.f. exact functor, $G\Delta$ is a d.t. if and only if $FG\Delta$ is a d.t. [05SQ]. Consider the diagram
$$
\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
FGX@>>>FGY@>>>FGZ@>{\xi_{GX}\circ F(\xi_X'\circ Gf)}>>T'FGX\\
@V{\varepsilon_X}VV@V{\varepsilon_Y}VV@V{\varepsilon_Z}VV@V{T'\varepsilon_X}VV\\
X@>>>Y@>>>Z@>\smash f>>T'X
\end{CD}
$$
It commutes: the left and middle square do by naturality of $\varepsilon$. On the other hand,
\begin{align*}
T'\varepsilon_X\circ\xi_{GX}\circ F(\xi_X'\circ Gf)
&=\varepsilon_{T'X}\circ FGf
&\text{by \eqref{comp}}\\
&=f\circ\varepsilon_Z
&\text{by naturality of }\varepsilon.
\end{align*}
Thus the diagram exhibits an isomorphism of triangles. Since the lower triangle, $\Delta$, is distinguished, so is the top one, $FG\Delta$.

I just found out that this result is proven in D. Murfet, Triangulated Categories Part I, Lemma 49.
